# Why is the default User Database on Parse.com called "_User"?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, parse-platform, backend

This might be a bad question, but I'm just curious as to why Parse would name their default User table as _User. I spent about 3 hours when I first worked with parse trying to figure out why nothing would return from my queries to that table.

Only after I hovered over the table in Chrome did I see in the bottom left of my window the proper name, "_User," at the end of the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a special class with special handling, not to be confused with classes created by the developer which all have the same behavior.  The same goes for _Installation too.  Yes, it has caused some confusion, which is unfortunate.  Usually our documentation carefully specifies it like this rather than using a string name:

JavaScript:

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
```

Android:

```
ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
```

iOS:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
```