# Parse.cloud.run success not called inside cloud job

Tags: parse-platform, cloud

I am just trying to make a simple call to a cloud function from within my job function.

here is my code.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("helloTest", function(request, status) { 
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); 
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

query.each(function(user){
  console.log("started job helloTest");
  Parse.Cloud.run("hello", {}, {

  success: function(output) {
    console.log("result from hello: ");
    console.log(output);
  },
  error: function(error) {
    console.log("hello failed");
   }
});
}).then(function() {
status.success("Weather push notifications have been sent.");
 }, function(error) {
    status.error(error.message);
 });

 });
```

this is the hello function.

```
 Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
 response.success("Hello world!");
});
```

so basically for every user that I have the function runs.

I2014-07-20T00:00:29.829Z] v298: Ran cloud function hello with:
  Input: {}
  Result: Hello world!
I2014-07-20T00:00:29.839Z] started job helloTest

I2014-07-20T00:00:29.850Z] started job helloTest

I2014-07-20T00:00:29.861Z] started job helloTest

I2014-07-20T00:00:29.868Z] started job helloTest

I2014-07-20T00:00:29.880Z] started job helloTest

I2014-07-20T00:00:29.891Z] started job helloTest

I2014-07-20T00:00:29.903Z] started job helloTest

so basically what is happening is it loops through my user table, but it won't call the hello cloud functions success.  Shouldn't if "Ran cloud function hello with:
  Input: {}
  Result: Hello world!"
 is printed to the console then I should be automatically kicked to the success function of cloud.run?

thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the default User Database on Parse.com called "\_User"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830601/why-is-the-default-user-database-on-parse-com-called-user)

Comment: Your question no longer makes sense since your edit... what do you mean "shouldn't when I call response.success in average stars in kicks me to the function ratings?"

Comment: You are right sorry it should make more sense now.

Comment: My main goal is to run a query through all my user table and for every user call a cloud function that I have made, but every time I try to call parse.cloud.run inside the query I cannot get anything back from the success from the parse.cloud.run.

Comment: You also need to add `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();` before you query the user class (as it is a secure class).

Comment: if I add that statement I get:  E2014-07-20T00:35:42.604Z] v299: Ran job helloTest with:
  Input: {}
  Failed with: unauthorized

Comment: Please show where you added it

Comment: I have added it.  I also have a Parse.initialize as well at the top of my file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to get anything to return from a parse.run call was if I put the job status inside the success of the call.  If I wanted to make multiple cloud calls within the same job I would have to nest the cloud calls and in the lowest child I would have to put the success call of the job before any of them would return.  There may be a better way to do this by putting job messages in the cloud.run calls, but with what I wanted to do this was the easiest way to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

It ran the `each` over empty results and then ran the success block. The results were empty because you were running a query on a class that doesn't exist.

The issue is that you're querying the `User` class, which is a special case (the actual name is `_User`). You should instead query for users as follows

```
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
```

Then your query will have actual rows to process and you'll get a better result.

NOTE: the `Role` and `Installation` classes work the same way.

In regards to running a Cloud Function within a job, I created the following test in my main.js:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("hello", function(request, response) {
  response.success("Hello world!");
});

Parse.Cloud.job("helloTest", function(request, status) {
  console.log("started job helloTest");
  Parse.Cloud.run("hello", {}, {
    success: function(output) {
      console.log("result from hello: ");
      console.log(output);
      status.success("test worked");
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log("hello failed");
      status.error(error);
    }
  });
});
```

And got the following logged output:

```
I2014-07-19T23:48:21.262Z] started job helloTest
I2014-07-19T23:48:21.312Z] v37: Ran cloud function hello with:
  Input: {}
  Result: Hello world!
I2014-07-19T23:48:21.375Z] result from hello: 
I2014-07-19T23:48:21.445Z] Hello world!
```

Comment: I do have a User table that contains my users logins and such that parse has made for me.  I am getting results back because I when I print user.id I do get the object id of the user in my user table.  Also if my table was empty it wouldn't run the function and give me the result of what happened when it was ran.

Comment: My point is that the User table can't be queried using "User", you have to use it's actual name "_User" or better yet create the query as shown in my answer as it is a special table.

Comment: The problem isn't the fact that I am not getting results though.  The query on the table is returning results.  I added: a console.log statement inside the query.each and it was ran and printed out " inside the query.each" I even moved the parse.cloud.run outside the query and it still didn't return.

Comment: The only way you could get results with the code shown is if you created your own class called "User" in addition to the one created for you by Parse (you would see two "User" classes in the Data Browser in this case, one of which would have the special user icon).

Comment: Okay I removed the query statement completely and only have the cloud.run inside my job.  I am still not getting a result from the cloud.run and the success function inside my cloud.run is not being called.  The point of this question is not the accuracy of my query, but the possible fault in my code when running the cloud.run function.

Comment: Thanks Tim! That worked, but you were right something is wrong with the query function.  So I added your code above, but it still isn't returning.  I made the modification to the question above.